# how do I remove an element from html site once loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

if the code is as below -

```
<div class="test1">
       <div class="bla1">
        </div>
    <a href="https://elitetech.com"> </a>
    </div>
```

how do I remove the href link above using javascript once the window has loaded?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Here on this site you are rather supposed to do your own research and try something first, and not just ask basic “how to” questions.

Answer (score 2):

Like this - assuming you want to remove the first instance of the link in a div with class test1

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector(".test1 a").remove()
})
```

```css
div.test1 { border:1px solid red }
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bla1">Bla 1</div>
  <a href="https://elitetech.com">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bla2">Bla 2</div>
  <a href="https://elitetech.com">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bla3">Bla 3</div>
  <a href="https://elitetech.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

Remove all of the links in divs with class test1

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".test1 a")].forEach(link => link.remove()); // IE11 compatible forEach
  // document.querySelectorAll(".test1 a").forEach(link => link.remove())
})
```

```css
div.test1 { border:1px solid red }
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bla1">Bla 1</div>
  <a href="https://elitetech.com">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bla2">Bla 2</div>
  <a href="https://elitetech.com">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bla3">Bla 3</div>
  <a href="https://elitetech.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. Very nice. Clever (appropriate) use of 'spread'. I learn so much from TRYING to participate here.

Comment: The spread is to force iteration for browser that do support spread and forEach but does not support forEach on an HTMLCollection

Comment: Only IE11 is missing the nodelist forEach now. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach